# How can I turn content on or off based on the day of the week?

Tags: php, jquery

I am using the jQuery cycle plugin to run a basic slider containing  3 slides (A, B, C) of a text header and an image.

I want to be able to display slide A and B on Mon, Wed, Fri, Sun;

then slide A and C on Tue, Thurs, Sat.

So I am looking for some kind of script or PHP based solution to turn content on and off based on the day of the week. Does anyone have any suggestions for the best approach?

Here is a link to an example of my code (can't get it to display fully in this post):

http://www.alexcreedy.com/slide/sample-code-for-forum.html

regards,
Alex

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current day of the week like so:

```
$day = date( "w", time());
```

From there, you can wrap whichever slide you want in an `if` to determine whether it gets displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a client-side solution.

Serve exactly the same HTML with all slides in place and with the following jQuery, which will remove the unwanted div before initialising the slider.

```
$(function() {
    var index = ($.inArray((new Date()).getDay(), [0, 1, 3, 5]) > -1) ? 2 : 1;
    $("#solutionFade").find('div').eq(index).remove().end().end().cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        speed: 500,
        timeout: 3000
    });
});
```

This will run on page load and the resulting slider will endure for the life of the page.

With a client-side approach, it would be possible to make the slider adapt as the time of day transitions through midnight, without reloading the page, but the solution would be significantly more complex.

Comment: Thanks alot this is an ideal solution for me.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, I'll calculate the sequence of 7 days in a week. Use setInterval() to check this sequence, and can cooperate with your cycle funxtion.